# How to put the rest of the row in a span in bootstrap?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row and then a `<div class="span4"></div>` inside, but sometimes I have two of this divs class="4", so I need a way to put `<div class="spanX"></div>` where X is the rest until 12.

I'm using Django but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: could you show us some code you have done in your template?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. One is by injecting a server-side value from Django into the template:

```
<div class="span{{ fill_column_span }}"></div>
```

or by using JavaScript to see what the current span total is, then determine the difference. This is untested, but should be pretty close.

```
// assumes jQuery, and that the column divs are only classed with span[x]
var existing_span = 0,
    fill_span,
    target = $('.target-class');

$.each(target.find('div[class*="span"]'), function(i, item) {
    existing_span += parseInt(item.class);
});

fill_span = 12 - existing_span;

$(target).find('div[class*="span"]:last').attr('class', 'span' + fill_span);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Brandon suggested, if you use this in your jinja2 template:

```
<div class="span{{ fill_column_span }}"></div>
```

then in the view, you can just get the last div width, knowing that all your divs are span4:

```
listYouCreateYourSpan4DivsFrom = ['foo','bar']
fill_column_span = 12 - len(listFromWichYouCreateYourSpan4Divs) * 4
```

Of course, put an if statement somewhere to run this only is len(listFromWichYouCreateYourSpan4Divs) < 3